# proof of accommodation in Europe for schengen visa

Tags: schengen, accommodation

i am going to tour Europe in mid Oct for around 15 days. i have already booked flight tickets. but the travel itinerary is not fixed. whether the travel itinerary provided by some tourist-sites like visareservation.com will be sufficient to apply for the schengen visa.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you make hotel reservations through sites like booking.com. You need not make payment at the time of booking, so you have flexibility to cancel should your itinerary change. I am a frequent traveller to the Schengen region from India and that is what I do.